# JPA switching from "drop-and-create-table" to "none" results in massive Bugs

Tags: java, exception, jpa, persistence

My team and me are currently working at a project using Hibernate-Validation and JPA.

Problem: we decided to use "drop-and-create-table" during the development-phase. everything worked just fine and as everything was implemented we changed the generation-mode to "none" (with a stable database running).

What it was doing before: We drop the table, create the table from our entities with specific attributes and fill the table with some datasets.

What it is doing now: We work on the existing, previously working, table (already filled with some data); but now some relations seem to be missing.

Now we have encountered a number of Exceptions during runtime and we can't locate them. It seems, that some attribute-relationships were deleted or something, because there are Exceptions (e.g. NullPointerExceptions) thrown, that were not thrown before.

Is there anything else we have to change in the persistence.xml, except the generation-mode?

here's the code for the persistance.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ticketline" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Veranstaltung</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Saal</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Reihe</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Platz</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Person</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Ort</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.News</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Kunde</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Kuenstler</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Kategorie</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Bestellung</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.BestellPosition</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.BaseEntity</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Auffuehrung</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Artikel</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Adresse</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Benutzer</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.Ticket</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.compositekeys.PlatzPK</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.compositekeys.ReihePK</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.compositekeys.SaalPK</class>
        <class>at.ticketline.entity.compositekeys.AuffuehrungPK</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/ticketline" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none" />              
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Stack-Trace:

```
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at at.ticketline.kassa.ui.editor.TicketSuchergebnisEditor$11.getText(TicketSuchergebnisEditor.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnLabelProvider.update(ColumnLabelProvider.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTableViewer.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2167)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.createItem(AbstractTableViewer.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefreshAll(AbstractTableViewer.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTableViewer.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer$2.run(AbstractTableViewer.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1404)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTableViewer.inputChanged(AbstractTableViewer.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ContentViewer.setInput(ContentViewer.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setInput(StructuredViewer.java:1690)
    at at.ticketline.kassa.ui.editor.TicketSuchergebnisEditor.createPartControl(TicketSuchergebnisEditor.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1245)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1198)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1597)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(PartStack.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(EditorStack.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(EditorSashContainer.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(EditorAreaHelper.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(EditorAreaHelper.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(EditorManager.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(EditorManager.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(EditorManager.java:666)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2942)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2756)
    at at.ticketline.kassa.ui.command.TicketSucheResultsCommandHandler.execute(TicketSucheResultsCommandHandler.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:247)
    at at.ticketline.kassa.ui.view.TicketSucheView.openEditor(TicketSucheView.java:246)
    at at.ticketline.kassa.ui.view.TicketSucheView$1.widgetSelected(TicketSucheView.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at at.ticketline.kassa.TicketlineApplication.start(TicketlineApplication.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Comment: _"but now some relations seem to be missing"_ So you know that your JPA model is inconsistent with database schema, and you want to fix it by changing `persistance.xml`? I'm not sure I quite follow...

Comment: Also, the stack trace of an exception tells you exactly where it happens. You shouldn't have any problem locating them.

Comment: As I already said, the database schema is working fine as long I use "drop-and-create-tables" as generation-mode. When I switch to "none" (with the database that worked well just a minute before) there seems to be some information missing to present the data correctly. But how can that happen? The database hasn't changed since the last build.. The only thing that changes is that the database is not set up before the build.. There are NO changes on the database schema..

Comment: Did you goto the database and made sure that the structure is intact?

Comment: Yes, i did. Database scheme is not changed. Data is not changed either.

Comment: drop-and-create-tables drops all your tables and recreates them from your entities mappings, so how can you say that the database schema is working fine: you don't use the same schema, since it's completely replaced by drop-and-create-tables? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes if that is the case it's quite an peculiar error. Can you also paste the stacktrace?

Comment: Every component of the project is working fine, as long as I drop-create the table just before I run the project (with drop-and-create-tables + filling table with data); After running with drop-and-create-tables there is an consistant database shema existing. Ok, NOW i set generation-mode (with working database) to "none" that the DB will not be created before the next build and i want to work on the existing DB that i just created the run before. But now the problems occur.

Comment: Just remove that entire property and see. Also post the stacktrace of errors that you said you are getting.

Comment: Whats this? `at.ticketline.eclipselink.platform.PatchedHSQLPlatform` I typed that into google and only this question popped up....

Comment: We are using HSQLDB and PatchedHSQLPlatform provides HSQL specific behavior. It's actually used to cast given SQL-Commands into HSQLDB compatible structure. I should've deleted that line, cause it's not necessary...

Comment: Even with those gone it's still giving you those errors?

Comment: As far as I can tell since this is the line with the NullPointerException `at.ticketline.kassa.ui.editor.TicketSuchergebnisEditor$11.getText(TicketSuchergebnisEditor.java:253)
` 11(which i think is some kind of an inner class) is null. Sor something near that area. Try to debug and identify the problem. Apart from that can't think of anything else. Sorry. It's not like you can give the production code for us to test :-D

Comment: Yes, errors still there.

Comment: Yeah, debug-session incoming. I always trace these errors down to the elementary JPA-implemented methods like merge(), persist(), findALL(), .. which should be working as long as the objects are in a persistable state or persisted in the DB.. something is wrong in the connection between database and entities.. i guess...... -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your database is missing some data.

When you run your populate in memory, you are populating the shared cache and the database.  However you are most likely no building your objects correctly.

Maybe you have transient fields that you set in memory, but when you read from the database, these transient fields are null.

Maybe you have bi-directional relationships and are not setting both sides of the relationships, so are not populating the database correctly.

Maybe you have not mapped some attributes correctly, so the data in the database is not correct.

My guess is that if you disabled the shared cache, you would have the same errors.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Disabling shared cache didn't lead to the same Exceptions. But disabling some other options did. (<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="0"/>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="None"/>)
 We found a pretty unsexy workaround. We call all DAOs during the build, that the cache has all data needed. The problem must be somewhere in our entities (e.g. wrong FetchType, etc.). I can definitely exclude Transcient Fields, cause we only have one transcient attribute set.